# How does making a brick wall *curvy* save material?

Tags: geometry, pi

Recently, I visited a college. The University of Virginia, to be exact. Just more of a sightseeing tour than anything. Whilst walking through a part of campus, I saw a brick wall that was built somewhat like this:

[image: This is what the wall looked like.]

I inquired about its curvy shape, and was told it was to save brick when building. I found this rather strange, considering each curve is one half times π times the diameter until it reached the same depth.

[image: The math]

And we know that the circumference will be larger than the diameter, so how could this save material of any kind? Was I just lied to?

Thanks in advance,
Joe

Answer (score 6):

You are correct that the wall is longer than a straight wall. What you are missing is that such walls can be built *thinner* than straight walls, which can more than offset the increase in length.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crinkle_crankle_wall) (emphasis added):

> The sinusoidal curves in the wall provide stability and help it to resist lateral forces, leading to **greater strength than a straight wall of the same thickness** of bricks without the need for buttresses.

Note that such walls are described as "sinusoidal", i.e. based on sine waves, which means they wouldn't be made up of semi-circles as in your diagram. Of course, any individual wall might not conform to any exact mathematical pattern...

Anyway, I found [a blog post](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2019/11/19/crinkle-crankle-calculus/) that does the math on the length of a sinusoidal wall:

> ...consider a section of wall 2π long. If the wall is in the shape of *a* sin(θ), then we need to find the arc length of this curve. This works out to the following integral.
>
> $$\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{1 + a^2 \cos^2(x)}\, dx$$
>
> The parameter *a* is the amplitude of the sine wave. If *a* = 0, we have a flat wave, i.e. a straight wall, as so the length of this segment is 2π = 6.2832. If *a* = 1, the integral is 7.6404.

The author concludes that if you replace a *two*-brick-thick straight wall with a *one*-brick-thick sinusoidal wall, you will save on bricks as long as the amplitude of the sine wave is below ~1.4422 (i.e. the point at which the wall has doubled in length).